# Pyspark error passing StructType to Schema

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Getting Error : **TypeError: 'StructType' object is not callable**, while passing `StructType` to the schema method. Below is the code:

```
final_schema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType(), True)])
dataframe = sc.read.text('/path').schema(final_schema)
```

Data is string type as below:

```
id
AO_01
AO_02
AO_03
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed the call to `sc.read.schema(final_schema).text('/path')` because `text(...)` will return a dataframe instance and need to set schema before that.